# Docker Desktop can't pull images but Docker on WSL2 and Ubuntu can

Tags: docker, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I've been running into an issue testing out a working, compliant docker environment. While Docker-CE on Ubuntu would work, getting the Docker Desktop app to work may be more viable in creating a compliant docker environment (ease of control). I run into this error when trying to pull from the Docker Desktop app:

[image: Photo of error]

This happens on both the corporate network and off, as well as on the VPN. There are no instances where I can successfully pull when using Docker Desktop. Using Docker on WSL on the same computer on the same network I can successfully use its full functionality. Please let me know if you have a solution to this. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try using the terminal?

Comment: I just tried it out - gives the same error just in command prompt. Another strange thing I noticed is that if I have docker on WSL running and then I start Docker Desktop, all of my images are gone. Its as if once I start Docker Desktop it replaces the Docker instance running on WSL.